# Считать данные из словаря из ячейки Pandas таблицы / фрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, словари

В таблице есть несколько полей, одно из них может содержать данные типа словарь. Как пример: `{"source":"ppc","domain":"domain.ru"}`, а может и просто строку, например `"data"`. Нужно в новое поле вывести значение поля "source", т.е. "ppc".
`'.str'` выдает null, можно как-то вытащить данные?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Пример данных:

```
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[ {"source":"ppc","domain":"domain.ru"}, "data", np.nan]})

In [46]: df
Out[46]:
                                          a
0  {'source': 'ppc', 'domain': 'domain.ru'}
1                                      data
2                                       NaN
```

решение:

```
df["source"] = \
    df["a"].map(lambda x: x.get("source", np.nan) 
                          if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan)
```

результат:

```
In [48]: df
Out[48]:
                                          a source
0  {'source': 'ppc', 'domain': 'domain.ru'}    ppc
1                                      data    NaN
2                                       NaN    NaN
```